# Count domain names with CTE Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to count domain names of emailaddresses where I would like to exclude some of the domain names from my results, but my query is getting timedout so i tried with cte table but its not excluding those domain names.

TRY 1:
I tried without cte table Query is getting timedout due to lot of computations going on.

TRY 2: I tried with CTE table but query is not excluding those domains which are in CTE table. So I am not understanding whats going on as I am not very used to using CTE tables.

Customers Table (This is a dummy dataset, In actual I have a very large dataset)

EmailAddress

```
xyz@gmail.com
abc1@gmail.com
xyz@yahoo.com
cvbv@yahoo.com
123@comcast.net
cvx1@comcast.net
abv@comcast.net
cxt@msn.com
abcd@msn.com
3453w@att.net
weszt@att.net
wrt@live.com
adcs@live.com


Try 1:
  SELECT
    Domain = RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress))
    ,EmailCount = COUNT(DISTINCT c.EmailAddress)
FROM Customers c
WHERE
    LEN(c.EmailAddress) > 0
    AND RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress))NOT IN ('gmail.com'
            ,'yahoo.com'
            ,'comcast.net'
           )
GROUP BY RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress))
ORDER BY EmailCount DESC

TRY 2: With CTE

with cte_x as ( SELECT RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress)) AS DOMAIN
FROM Customers c
WHERE LEN(c.EmailAddress) > 0
 AND RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress)) NOT IN
   ('gmail.com'
            ,'yahoo.com'
            ,'comcast.net')) 
SELECT RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress)) AS DOMAIN_1 ,
 COUNT(DISTINCT c.EmailAddress) AS EmailCount
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN cte_x ON c.EmailAddress=cte_x.DOMAIN
WHERE cte_x.DOMAIN IS NULL
GROUP BY
RIGHT(c.EmailAddress, LEN(c.EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', c.EmailAddress))

Result Coming:

Domain      count
gmail.com      2
yahoo.com       2
comcast.net     3
msn.com        2
att.net        2
live.com       2

Results Expected:

Domain      count
msn.com        2
att.net        2
live.com       2
```

Comment: What about an email address with a subdomain, e.g. `joe.blow@somewhere.co.uk`?  Fishing out domains (and subdomains) can be not straightforward.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..Well i don't want to exclude subdomains as it becomes too tedious, just these basic domains where i have 1000 of emailaddresses with these domains. This will solve my problem.

Comment: [Your first query seems to already be generating the output you want](https://rextester.com/WSH62216).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..My first query generates results but it gets timed out in my system. Thats why i am trying with  Cte table.Also I have 1000 of email address so it would be hard to write all in cte table. can we just write gmail,yahoo and not to include those in results?

Comment: Well timing out may just mean you have too much data.  Next time, store each domain in a separate column as you are inserting it, to avoid this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..how to do that? I have no idea how to do it..can you help me with sample..I am not strong with cte tables

Comment: Not sure what your situation is here ... maybe try putting the emails into an actual table, if you are not already doing that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.I already have actual emailaddress in customers table in my database. In cte I am trying to just exclude those domains. If that make sense to avoid timeout issues.